# Are Tina and Queenie Goldstein (Fantastic Beasts and where to find them) related to Anthony Goldstein (Harry Potter)?

Tags: harry-potter, fantastic-beasts

In fantastic beasts and where to find them, there are characters called Porpentina and Queenie Goldstein. In Harry Potter, there’s a minor character called Anthony Goldstein. Are they related?

Comment: They both have the same common Jewish name. That means they should be at least extremely distantly related.

Comment: I'm not sure why this has attracted downvotes. Given the wizarding obsession with families, this seems a perfectly sensible question.

Comment: That being said, the question of their relation to Anthony Golstein is directly addressed in another question.

Comment: @user14111 -  As long as you live, that will be an unsolved riddle in your mind...

Comment: It's not a duplicate question, it just so happens that a different question uses the same source as evidence.

Answer (score 5):

Per [JKRs twitter](https://twitter.com/jk_rowling/status/632611629843263488), yes they are related. It's not explained how.

> **@jk_rowling:** *Well, I think it's widely known that that characters of (Porpen)tina and Queenie are sisters, but not that their surname is Goldstein.*
>
> **‏@marknffc7:** *any r[e]lation to Anthony Goldstein?*
>
> **@jk_rowling:** **Yes (but distant).**